# Handling data fetching in non-route components with React SSR frameworks

Tags: reactjs, next.js, remix.run

I'm exploring React SSR frameworks (like Next.js, Remix, etc.) and have a question regarding data fetching in non-route components. In these frameworks, data loading is often handled at the route level. However, I'm curious about the best practices for components that aren't directly tied to a specific route, such as a reusable `LikeButton`.

In React SSR frameworks, is it possible to define data fetching and mutation logic within non-route component while still benefiting from SSR? Maybe Server components could be a better fit for what I´m looking for?

Comment: Here's a pattern for Remix https://www.epicweb.dev/full-stack-components

Comment: I have read about it and also watched Kent C. Dodds' video, but I'm still unsure if this pattern allows us to fetch initial data for the component on the server

Comment: Remix will only fetch your loaders automatically from routes. If you want your components to handle data fetching, you'll need to handle it manually or pass initial data as props from your route component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the latest version of Next.js, data fetching can be performed at the component level using React Server Components, like:

```
export default async function LikeButton() {
  const likes = await fetchLikes()
 
  return <div>{likes}</div>
}
```